My backend container has "ECONNREFUSED" from my MySQL container, on the same network
I'm learning full stack development by creating a project with a MySQL database/express API. My application was working "properly", then I tried to dockerize it. I wrote a docker-compose file:
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --bind-address='0.0.0.0'
    container_name: mysql_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: housesdb
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - app-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my-network

version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --bind-address='0.0.0.0'
    container_name: mysql_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: housesdb
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - app-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my-network

  api:
    build: ./Backend
    container_name: node_api
    ports:
      - "3005:3005"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_NAME: housesdb
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - my-network

  web:
    build: ./frontend-jm
    container_name: react_app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    
    depends_on:
      - db
      - api
    
    networks:
      - my-network
      
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  app-data:

The problem is that my node.js API has an "ECONNREFUSED" error while trying to get a connection with the MySQL container. I can connect to the MySQL database with MySQL Workbench from my host.
At first, I thought that MySQL was blocking access from app when the app address wasn't localhost. To verify it, I started a MySQL container like this: docker run -it --rm mysql:tag --verbose --help, but I can see that the value "bind-address" from the configuration file of MySQL is "*" in the terminal.
After I made some research, I tried this command:
alter user 'root'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password'

And I then had this error:

Error Code: 1524. Plugin 'mysql_native_password' is not loaded

How can I fix this?
EDIT :
So after some research I finally understood what was going on.
Since mysql 8.0, the default authentication is caching_sha2_password, prior 8.0, it was mysql_native_password.
That mean that, in order to resolve my issue, I have either :

have to change something about the way I interact with mysql server 8.0, to be conform with the caching_sha2_password plugin, but I don't know how
or I have to set my mysql:8.0 container default-authentication-plugin to mysql_native_password

To achieve the second solution, I had to write this in my docker-compose, under "image: mysql:8.0" :

"command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"

Then, it's ALMOST finally work, but I'm not okay with the fact that I'm using a deprecated authentication solution, but for now, I don't know how to work around with caching_sha2_password.
To make it work properly with my second container, I have to restart manually my node_api container. Simply because the first time the docker-compose is building and loads the containers, the mysql container "restart" and take too much time for the node_api container to connect to it. But after this "first time", it will work fine and no need to restart manually the node_api container.
Please note that this command is working with mysql:8.0, but will not work with mysql:latest, simply because the variable "default-authentication-plugin" is deprecated. Instead, use the command : "--authentication_policy=mysql_native_password", but I couldn't say how it work.

Please read: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

DB_HOST should be the container_name, i.e. mysql_db instead of just db.

Is it possible your application is starting up before the database is ready?  If you run docker-compose up -d once and it fails, and you run it a second time, does it work?  (Your DB_HOST setting is fine and Compose sets up the Docker DNS so that containers are reachable by their Compose service name too.)

Unfortunately,, restarting my node container a second or a third time, still doesn't make it work.

In MySQL 8.1 and later, mysql_native_password is deprecated and you should use caching_sha2_password instead. To work with caching_sha2_password, use the mysql2 library in your Node.js application, which supports this authentication method. This should resolve your connection issue.
